# How to improve the condition caused by intimidate

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions

An intimidated person becomes shaken for a specific number of rounds. I am looking for a feat that makes the person frightend or even worse. I am a Level 3 Character. What I found yet was Enforcer and Antagonize that are related to intimidate but they are no help in my case. Are there any others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Signature Skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/signature-skill-general/)([Intimidate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/intimidate)) does what you are looking for, but you need to wait until lvl 5 for it to begin doing something and lvl 10 to really kick off.

> 5 Ranks: If you exceed the DC to demoralize a target by at least 10, it is frightened for 1 round and shaken thereafter.* A Will save (DC = 10 + your number of ranks in Intimidate) negates the frightened condition, but the target is still shaken, even if it has the stalwart ability.
>
> 10 Ranks: If you exceed the DC to demoralize a target by at least 10, it is panicked for 1 round or frightened for 1d4 rounds (your choice) and shaken thereafter.* A Will save (DC = 10 + your number of ranks in Intimidate) negates the frightened or panicked condition, but the target is still shaken, even if it has the stalwart ability.

Moreover if you are not a rogue your GM may not allow you to take this feat. Personally I would allow it but you should better ask.

At level 3 there is no feat that I know of that improve the effect of your intimidations.

Comment: Should also note that this uses unchained rules. I have had a DM who had ruled to not have unchained rules in his game. However if they are allowed this would be the better long term choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Damnation feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/damnation-feats/) if you are okay with being a little evil!

[Soulless Gaze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/damnation-feats/soulless-gaze-damnation/) Improves your intimidation, and with 2 damnation feats, you can intimidate the same opponent multiple times to turn shaken into fear! With 4, you can even intimidate as a swift action! Allowing you to use your swift, and standard to cause fear in a single turn!

Comment: That is a *lot* of feats for that effect. Some analysis of the efficiency of this route seems warranted: are there enough truly *good* Damnation feats to make this worthwhile?

Comment: Agreed. 2 or 4 Feats for the desired effect can be a lot. However fighters and other classes that get a large amount of bonus feats can mitigate this. And if DM allows, can be gained as early as lv 1-3 (If Human Or Fighter). And if your not super into efficiency it adds quite a bit of flavor to your character simply through the nature of the feat.